# Android Maven Project on Jenkins

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I have tried using Jenkins with my Android project which I'm using Maven for.  I have tried following this tutorial except the emulator part since I don't have any tests (yet). http://vitorbaptista.com/continuous-integration-for-android-apps-with-jenkins-and-maven3/

I am getting the following error when I try building my project in Jenkins:

> message : Failed to execute goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources
>   (default-generate-sources) on project ....: Execution
>   default-generate-sources of goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources
>   failed: Could not find tool 'aapt'. Please provide a proper Android
>   SDK directory path as configuration parameter
>   ... in the plugin . As an
>   alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline:
>   -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME. cause : Execution default-generate-sources of goal
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources
>   failed: Could not find tool 'aapt'. Please provide a proper Android
>   SDK directory path as configuration parameter
>   ... in the plugin . As an
>   alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline:
>   -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.

Here is my configuration for Android and Maven:

**Jenkins**
[image]
[image]
(that folder is the right one, I've checked a million times)
[image]

**Project**

[image]

I have tried even chmod 777'ing the path to my SDK directory in the case Jenkins doesn't have access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it was as simple as installing the platform tools.  Since I have always worked with the SDK via UI, I haven't thought about the installation of the platform tools.  After installing the platform tools, everything built.

The command was as simple as:

```
[sdkdir]/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter platform-tool
```